# Running Revel package on windows fails

Tags: go, revel

When I run my packaged Revel app on Windows I get the following error:

C:\app>go run main.go
ERROR 2015/12/09 16:02:21 revel.go:276: Failed to import  with error: import "": invalid import path
exit status 1

I'm running version: v0.12.0

Is this a known issue?

UPDATE:
I revoke this question. Works perfectly well. Packaged artifacts from running (revel package appname) go to current directory. It was creating main.go in my apps's src directory, but this isn't valid.

Comment: did you setup your workspace properly?

Comment: yes it's correct. the package command outputs the zipped folder to the current directory.

Answer (score -1):

i would think you should place your source code under "%GOPATH%\src",  but you are running your app under "C:\app". are you sure you are working at the right folder?

another thing i notice is, you should run your revel app with revel command. I don`t think "go run" will compatible with revel.

[Here is a sample revel app repo](https://github.com/shrimpy/reveltry) that runs on Azure App Service (OS is windows). Please reference [RevelDeploy.cmd](https://github.com/shrimpy/reveltry/blob/master/RevelDeploy.cmd) and [CustomRun.bat](https://github.com/shrimpy/reveltry/blob/master/CustomRun.bat), should be able to provide you some guidance.

Comment: Like I said, I revoke the question. It's working just fine. Thanks.